# Get count of orders created monthly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to list the total number of orders for the last 12 rolling months (not including the current month).

This is my query:

```
Select
Year(CreatedOn)*100+Month(CreatedOn) YearMonth,
Count(*) OrderCount
From Orders
Where DateDiff(MM,CreatedOn,GetUTCDate()) Between 1 And 12
Group By Year(CreatedOn), Month(CreatedOn)
Order By YearMonth
```

As expected, I am getting the results correctly. However, when there are no orders in a specific month, the month is excluded from the result completely. I would like to show that month with 0. See sample result:

```
201809  70
201810  8
201811  53
201812  67
201901  15
201902  13
201903  10
201905  12
201908  9
```

See the missing months 201904, 201906 and 201907. There should be a total of 12 rows.

The query should be executable within a sub-query using `For XML Path` so that I can get a comma separated list of orders in the last 12 months.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Someone care to explain the negative vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this-

```
WITH R(N) AS
(
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT N+1 
    FROM R
    WHERE N < 12
)
SELECT REPLACE(LEFT(CAST (DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,(DATEADD(MONTH,-N,GetUTCDate()))),0) AS DATE),7),'-','') AS [YearMonth],ISNULL(o.OrderCount,0) as OrderCount 
FROM R A
LEFT JOIN 
(       
    Select
    Year(CreatedOn)*100+Month(CreatedOn) YearMonth,
    Count(*) OrderCount
    From Orders
    Where DateDiff(MM,CreatedOn,GetUTCDate()) Between 1 And 12
    Group By Year(CreatedOn), Month(CreatedOn)
) O ON O.YearMonth=REPLACE(LEFT(CAST (DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,(DATEADD(MONTH,-N,GetUTCDate()))),0) AS DATE),7),'-','')
Order By REPLACE(LEFT(CAST (DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,(DATEADD(MONTH,-N,GetUTCDate()))),0) AS DATE),7),'-','');
```

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot use temp tables. This needs to fit inside a subquery.

Comment: This really is an elegant solution - almost the same as Gordons. I think I will be able to manage with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to generate the rows that you want somehow.  One method uses a recursive CTE:

```
with dates as (
      select Year(getdate())*100+Month(getdate()) as yearmonth,
             1 as n, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1) as yyyymm
      union all
      select year(dateadd(month, -1, yyyymm)) * 100 + month(dateadd(month, -1, yyyymm),
             n + 1,
             dateadd(month, -1, yyyymm)
      from cte
      where n < 12
     ),
     q as (
      <your query here>
     )
select d.yearmonth, coalesce(q.orders, 0) as orders
from dates d left join
     q
     on d.yearmonth = q.yearmonth;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works really well! But I need a simpler method to be able to fit into a sub-query. I have added that to the OP. I will try to see if I can use it where I need to.